# FragmentTransaction replace not actually replacing but drawing the two on top of each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I've been following http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html to set up a navigation drawer in my app. Once an item in the drawer has been selected, the current fragment should be removed and replaced with a new ListFragment. However, both remain and are drawn on top of each other.

mainpage.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mainListFragment"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:name="com.example.SpeakEasy.MainPageListFragment"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="2dp">

        </fragment>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light">
    </ListView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainPage.java:

```
public class MainPage extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    public static AmazonClientManager clientManager = null;
    protected UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private String[] categoryTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        clientManager = new AmazonClientManager(getSharedPreferences("speakeasySDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Main Feed");
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

        categoryTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigationDrawerCategories);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getTitle());
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, categoryTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


    }
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps fragments in the main content view
     */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Following not yet implemented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new HomePageListFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainListFragment, fragment).commit(); //R.id.content_frame didn't work either
                break;
        }

        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(categoryTitles[position] + "Quotes");
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

}
```

Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have fragment declared in the layout file but you are trying to use it in a dynamic way. Replace the fragment with FrameLayout/LinearLayout.

Then you can do transaction.replace(id,fragment,tag).commit();

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Why is having a fragment inside of a RelativeLayout different than having a ListView inside of a LinearLayout as in the example on the dev guide? I'm still replacing the entire layout when I replace R.id.content_frame

Comment: When you have a fragment in a layout, you are expecting it to behave in a static way. This would be created and attached to the activity after the activity is created without you adding any code inside your activity apart from setContentView(). In cases where the fragments change based on selection or other criteria, the practice to have a empty container in the layout. And whenever we want, we would use fragmenttransaction and replace or add fragment as we want to. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html   pardon my typo as im replying from a mobile device